# How does the automatic full qualification of class names work, in Python? [relevant to object pickling]

Tags: python, class, import, pickle, fully-qualified-naming

(It is possible to directly jump to the question, further down, and to skip the introduction.)

There is a common difficulty with pickling Python objects from user-defined classes:

```
# This is program dumper.py
import pickle

class C(object):
    pass

with open('obj.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(C(), f)
```

In fact, trying to get the object back from another program `loader.py` with

```
# This is program loader.py
with open('obj.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```

results in

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'C'
```

In fact, the class is pickled by name ("C"), and the `loader.py` program does not know anything about `C`.  A common solution consists in importing with

```
from dumper import C  # Objects of class C can be imported

with open('obj.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)
```

However, this solution has a few drawbacks, including the fact that all the classes referenced by the pickled objects have to be imported (there can be many); furthermore, the local namespace becomes polluted by names from the `dumper.py` program.

Now, a solution to this consists of fully qualifying objects prior to pickling:

```
# New dumper.py program:
import pickle
import dumper  # This is this very program!

class C(object):
    pass

with open('obj.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dumper.C(), f)  # Fully qualified class
```

Unpickling with the original `loader.py` program above now works directly (no need to do `from dumper import C`).

**Question**: Now, other classes from `dumper.py` seem to be automatically fully qualified upon pickling, and I would love to know how this works, and whether this is a reliable, documented behavior:

```
import pickle
import dumper  # This is this very program!

class D(object):  # New class!
    pass

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = D()  # *NOT* fully qualified

with open('obj.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dumper.C(), f)  # Fully qualified pickle class
```

Now, unpickling with the original `loader.py` program also works (no need to do `from dumper import C`); `print obj.d` gives a *fully qualified* class, which I find surprising:

```
<dumper.D object at 0x122e130>
```

This behavior is very convenient, since only the top, pickled object has to be fully qualified with the module name (`dumper.C()`).  But is this behavior reliable and documented?  how come that classes are pickled by name ("D") but that the unpickling decides that the pickled `self.d` attribute is of class `dumper.D` (and not some local  `D` class)?

**PS: The question, refined**: I just noticed a few interesting details that might point to an answer to this question:

In the pickling program `dumper.py`, `print self.d` prints `<__main__.D object at 0x2af450>`, with the first `dumper.py` program (the one without `import dumper`).  On the other hand, doing `import dumper` and creating the object with `dumper.C()` in `dumper.py` makes `print self.d` print `<dumper.D object at 0x2af450>`: the `self.d` attribute is automatically qualified by Python!  So, it appears that the `pickle` module has no role in the nice unpickling behavior described above.

The question is thus really: why does Python convert `D()` into the fully qualified `dumper.D`, in the second case?  is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what happens: when importing `dumper` (or doing `from dumper import C`) from within `dumper.py`, *the whole program is parsed again* (this can be seen by inserting a print in the module).  This behavior is expected, because `dumper` is not a module that was already loaded (`__main__` is considered loaded, however)–it is not in `sys.modules`.

As illustrated in Mark's answer, importing a module naturally qualifies all the names defined in the module, so that `self.d = D()` is interpreted as being of class `dumper.D` when re-evaluating file `dumper.py` (this is equivalent to parsing `common.py`, in Mark's answer).

Thus, the `import dumper` (or `from dumper import C`) trick is explained, and pickling fully qualifies not only class `C` but also class `D`.  This makes unpickling by an external program easier!

This also shows that `import dumper` done in `dumper.py` forces the Python interpreter to parse the program twice, which is neither efficient nor elegant.  Pickling classes in a program and unpickling them in *another* one is therefore probably best done through the approach outlined in Mark's answer: pickled classes should be in a separate module.

Answer (score 3):

When your classes are defined in your main module, that's where pickle expects to find them when they are unpickled.  In your first case, the classes were defined in the main module, so when loader runs, *loader* is the main module and pickle can't find the classes.  If you look at the content of `obj.pickle`, you'll see then name `__main__` exported as the namespace of your C and D classes.

In your second case, dumper.py imports itself.  Now you actually have two separate sets of C and D classes defined: one set in `__main__` namespace and one set in `dumper` namespace.  You serialize the one in the `dumper` namespace (look in `obj.pickle` to verify).

pickle will attempt to dynamically import a namespace if it is not found, so when loader.py runs *pickle itself* imports dumper.py and the dumper.C and dumper.D classes.

Since you have two separate scripts, dumper.py and loader.py, it only makes sense to define the classes they share in a common import module:

#### common.py

```
class D(object):
    pass

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = D()
```

#### loader.py

```
import pickle

with open('obj.pickle','rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)

print obj
```

#### dumper.py

```
import pickle
from common import C

with open('obj.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(C(),f)
```

Note that even though dumper.py dumps `C()` in this case pickle knows that it is a `common.C` object (see `obj.pickle`).  When loader.py runs, it will dynamically import common.py and succeed loading the object.

Comment: Good advice, about using a common module.  The real question is the one that is now in the PS in the original question: when the code for your `common.py` is in `dumper.py`, why is `self.d = D()` fully qualified by Python when `dumper.C()` is created?  Your `common.py` might point to the answer: in your example, Python obviously makes `self.d = D()` be a `common.D` object; what is less clear is how Python does the same when `import dumper` is done in `dumper.py`, and whether this is documented somewhere…

Comment: self.d = D() is in the context of the dumper namespace, when you create a dumper.C object.  If you instead create a __main__.C object, you'd get a __main__.D object.

Comment: Yes, that's the exact reason why the `import dumper` trick works (my answer contains details)…

Comment: I think that your answer is the right solution to the "how to properly pickle classes for other programs" problem (+1 from me for this).  I marked my answer as the accepted one because the original question, while related to pickling, is really about full name qualification.