# Store object using Python pickle, and load it into different namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'd like to pass object state between two Python programs (one is my own code running standalone, one is a [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/) view), and different namespaces. Somewhat related questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947904/how-can-i-pickle-a-nested-class-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009169/how-does-the-automatic-full-qualification-of-class-names-work-in-python-relev), but I can't quite follow through with them for my scenario.

My own code defines a global class (i.e. `__main__` namespace) of somewhat complexish structure:

```
# An instance of this is a colorful mess of nested lists and sets and dicts.
class MyClass :
    def __init__(self) :
        data = set()
        more = dict()
        ... 

    def do_sth(self) :
        ...
```

At some point I pickle an instance of this class:

```
c = MyClass()
# Fill c with data.

# Pickle and write the MyClass instance within the __main__ namespace.
with open("my_c.pik", "wb") as f :
    pickle.dump(c, f, -1)
```

A `hexdump -C my_c.pik` shows that the first couple of bytes contain `__main__.MyClass` from which I assume that the class is indeed defined in the global namespace, and that this is somehow a requirement for reading the pickle. Now I'd like to load this pickled `MyClass` instance from within a Pyramid view, which I assume is a different namespace:

```
# In Pyramid (different namespace) read the pickled MyClass instance.
with open("my_c.pik", "rb") as f :
    c = pickle.load(f)
```

But that results in the following error:

```
File ".../views.py", line 60, in view_handler_bla
  c = pickle.load(f)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyClass'
```

It seems to me that the `MyClass` definition is missing in whatever namespace the view code executes? I had hoped (assumed) that pickling is a somewhat opaque process which allows me to read a blob of data into whichever place I chose. (More on Python's class names and namespaces is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).)

How can I handle this properly? (Ideally without having to import stuff across...) Can I somehow find the current namespace and inject `MyClass` (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947904/how-can-i-pickle-a-nested-class-in-python#1948057) answer seems to suggest)?

**Poor Solution**

It seems to me that if I refrain from defining and using `MyClass` and instead fall back to plain built-in datatypes, this wouldn't be a problem. In fact, I could "serialize" the `MyClass` object into a sequence of calls that pickle the individual elements of the `MyClass` instance:

```
# 'Manual' serialization of c works, because all elements are built-in types.
pickle.dump(c.data, f, -1)
pickle.dump(c.more, f, -1)
...
```

This would defeat the purpose of wrapping data into classes though.

**Note**

Pickling takes care only of the state of a class, *not* of any functions defined in the scope of the class (e.g. `do_sth()` in the above example). That means that loading a `MyClass` instance into a different namespace without the proper class definition loads only the instance data; calling a missing function like `do_sth()` will cause an [AttributeError](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#AttributeError).

Comment: have you thought about using [named tuples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970608/what-are-named-tuples-in-python)? They should be picklable, too.

Comment: @User: That'd be part of the "poor solution" above where I fall back to plainer types. Yes, I tried it and it works. But that's an avoidant workaround, not an answer to my question ;-)

Comment: You could simply define the `MyClass` in a module different than `__main__`... your first program should use some custom module to define that class, and then you just have to add it to the path for the second program.

Comment: @Bakuriu: How would resolve the issue with the `__main__` namespace which the Pyramid code doesn't execute in? I can't import that module in the `__main__` namespace in the other program.

Comment: If you define `MyClass` in an other module, say `A`, then python will *not* look in the `__main__` namespace to load the class but it will search for the `A` module and load the class from there (since the name saved in the pickle file will be `A.MyClass` instead of `__main__.MyClass`). This completely avoids the whole problem. Defining things in `__main__` should be done only for small scripts or things that you don't plan to need somewhere else.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I've just added a note to the question. It looks like I will *have* to load the proper class definition (instead of faking a symbolic excuse) to ensure that all functions are available to the instance read from the pickle.

Answer (score 13):

Use `dill` instead of `pickle`, because `dill` by default pickles by serializing the class definition and not by reference.

```
>>> import dill
>>> class MyClass:
...   def __init__(self): 
...     self.data = set()
...     self.more = dict()
...   def do_stuff(self):
...     return sorted(self.more)
... 
>>> c = MyClass()
>>> c.data.add(1)
>>> c.data.add(2)
>>> c.data.add(3)
>>> c.data
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> c.more['1'] = 1
>>> c.more['2'] = 2
>>> c.more['3'] = lambda x:x
>>> def more_stuff(self, x):  
...   return x+1
... 
>>> c.more_stuff = more_stuff
>>> 
>>> with open('my_c.pik', "wb") as f:
...   dill.dump(c, f)
... 
>>>
```

Shut down the session, and restart in a new session…

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('my_c.pik', "rb") as f:
...   c = dill.load(f)
... 
>>> c.data
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> c.more
{'1': 1, '3': <function <lambda> at 0x10473ec80>, '2': 2}
>>> c.do_stuff()
['1', '2', '3']
>>> c.more_stuff(5)
6
```

Get `dill` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill

Comment: And a "dilled" object (with its class) can be then read back into any namespace?

Comment: Yes.  It can even be read back into the same namespace where the class definition has changed, and it still works.

Comment: I've just added a note to the original question regarding the functions of a class—they are *not* pickled; only state is. It seems that [dill](http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/pathos/browser/dill/tests) does indeed include the functions defined within `class` scope? So a "dilled" class instance can then be loaded into a different namespace *and* its functions can be called (without having to include the module)?

Comment: Yes. Using `dill` to serialize a class instance will also serialize the class definition, which includes the class methods.  You can even serialize an instance of a class method, and it will work similarly as well.

Comment: I added some methods both in the class def and dynamically, to demonstrate your new edits.

Comment: Oh now *that* is very neat :) Let me give this a shot! (Bummer, no [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) yet...)

Comment: A little off-topic: would `dill` be able to take a coredump snapshot when an exception was caught and store it away for post-mortem debugging? Could I then load that coredump into an interpreter and poke around?

Comment: `Exceptions` can be pickled by `dill`, but `Tracebacks` can't yet.  A `Traceback` depends on the `Frame` object, and the `Frame` object would require a "pickle" of sorts of the GIL -- which as far as I know can't be done.  I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

On `pickle.load`, the module `__main__` needs to have a function or class called `MyClass`. This does not need to be the original class with the original source code. You can put other methods in it. It should work.

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

with open("my_c.pik", "rb") as f :
    c = pickle.load(f)
```

**Solution 2**

Use the [`copyreg` module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/copyreg.html) which is used to register constructors and pickle functions to pickle specific objects. This is the example given by the module for a complex number:

```
def pickle_complex(c):
    return complex, (c.real, c.imag)

copyreg.pickle(complex, pickle_complex, complex)
```

**Solution 3**

Override the [`persistent_id` method](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler.persistent_id) of the Pickler and Unpickler. `pickler.persistent_id(obj)` shall return an identifier that can be resolved by `unpickler.persistent_id(id)` to the object.

Comment: I don't have (want to touch) the Pyramid code. But your answer goes along with what [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947904/how-can-i-pickle-a-nested-class-in-python#1948057) answer suggests: inject a symbol and (meaningless) type information. In fact, when I add `setattr(sys.modules["__main__"], "MyClass", type(MyClass()))` before the `pickle.load()` call, everything seems to work. Note that `MyClass` doesn't need to be defined anywhere. Just feels rather *hackish* to me ... :-)

Comment: There is a solution to this, too. It is called `persistent_id`. This method shall be overwritten by subclasses of `Pickler` and `Unpickler`. It allows returning ids and resolving them. Alternatively you can use `copyreg` module. Have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the three suggestions. Which one is the cleanest and most pythonic one? It seems that both solutions 2 and 3 would require carrying additional functionality between the two pieces of Python code in order to ensure that `MyClass` instances can be pickled/unpickled across namespaces...

Comment: I would use copyreg. To me the problem is - what is a MyClass instance? If you really need the whole module for an instance to exist - you must share the module. Maybe you only want to have MyClass instances that have different functionality depending on the program they are in - then I would recomment copyreg as a plug-in mechanism. If you use persistent_id you would also need to subclass the Pickler class and the Unpickler class or monkey-patch it in. So I would choose copyreg. There is a fouth solution which is storing the whole information of the class into the dump (not good).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use *cloudpickle*:

https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle

It enabled me to easily send a pickled class file to another machine and unpickle it using *cloudpickle* again.